# How were the security sensors modified without the accessing codes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode “[The Game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Game_(episode))” Wesley comes in the Engineering, and asks Robin if she got the security tracking codes.

Soon after, on the Bridge, LaForge says, 'He's done something to the internal security sensors'.

How he could modify them without the accessing codes?

Comment: Messing around with the isolinear chips for the internal sensors is a possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Without the access codes, Wesley was not able to disable all the security tracking systems

Wesley asks Robin to access the codes for the security tracking system.

> **WESLEY**: Okay. When you get there, start accessing the codes for the **security tracking system**. There's something I want to try.

Later on, when being chased, LaForge complains that Wesley has done "something" to the internal security **sensors**:

> **LAFORGE**: I can't track him, sir. He's done something to the **internal security sensors**. I'll try bypassing his subcommands. Hold on. I'm picking up a piece of his trail, sir. Sensors show power activation in transporter room three. That would put him somewhere on deck six.

It seems that Wesley did not manage to disable all internal security tracking systems: LaForge can track him via power activation in Transporter Room Three, and Worf can even use thermal sensors:

> **RIKER**: Where the hell is he?
>   **WORF**: I am attempting to isolate him with thermal sensors.
>   **RIKER**: Narrow the scan field. Go deck by deck if you have to.

A possible explanation is that without Robin's codes, Wesley manages to disable some, but not all security tracking systems. Considering that Wesley had been working on the sensors (albeit not the internal ones) before in the same episode, I think that this is the most likely explanation.

Comment: I always read it that he'd jiggered with the sensors by doing things that didn't necessarily require the *command* codes to disable them. He's pointed them at the ceiling or set the computer to run endless diagnostics or something

Comment: This seems to me the most plausible possibility. The sensors don't require any code, but other systems do. Wesley wants be sure, and he wish to deactivate all possibilities

Comment: LaForge refers to Wesley having buggered up the sensors with *sub*routines. He's clearly doing something clever that's allowed with his access levels. I seem to recall that the same trick is tried later in the show, running a diagnostic to take key systems offline.

Comment: @Valorum this seems necessary to integrate the answer, because in fact also the internal sensors should be require some access code. But on them probably it can be done something extra bypassing the constraint